# Is there any existing tool to recursively substitute the UID/GID by any other?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chown

*I used to own the UID #1000 on my personal computers as it is the default in most Linux distributions. On my new computer, I own a completely different UID (which I cannot change).*

**I want to access my former `/home` in my former hard drive.**

I could `chmod` or `chown` my way into the former HD. With the recursive flag, this is actually very easy. The thing is that I don't want to bork my former `/home`: I might use it soon in another computer.

So I want a way to recursively substitute the UID in that disk by mine. To be more precise, if `fileA` is owned by UID 1000, I want its ownership to be given to UID 2000 (for instance). However, if `fileB` is owned by UID 1240, I don't want its ownership to be changed. This is why I can't directly use `chown -R`.

Comment: You could always change the ownership and permissions of your home directory, copy it to your new machine, then change it back to the original value.  Just an option since its so easily done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the man page.

`chown --from=CURRENT_OWNER:CURRENT_GROUP -R NEW_OWNER:NEW_GROUP DIRECTORY`

`chown --from=1000 -R 2000 /former/home`

Comment: When I was young, it used to be *rtfm*. I wonder whether that still exists...

Comment: When I was young, people were not bluntly commenting with offense as the **only** objective without adding any information whatsoever. In my youth, such useless people were said to clear off (to say it gently). Now, that said, I did not know such functionality existed in `chown`. This is the problem of man page: it is great to know how to use a specific command, but it is a crappy to *look for* the right command. A much better way is to use Google/whatever to look for the right command and *then* the man page. Since Google didn't know about it, I assumed it did not exist, hence my question.